# Random number and letter generator in JFrame - Java

Tags: random, jframe

Okay I have the code so far but I can not get it to show up on the screen because the variable is a char and needs to be a string. Is there a way of converting this or a different method? Here's the code.

```
       char num;

       final String alphabet = "0123456789ABCDE";
        final int N = alphabet.length();

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
           num = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N));

        }

  final JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();   
        final JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText(num); // this is where I'm having problems
```

Everything is being added and there is more this is just shortened.
The numbers and letters should pop up when I press a button. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
       text += String.valueOf(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N))); //Shouldn't even implicitly need String.valueOf(char)...

    }

label1.setText(String.valueOf(text));
```

Comment: That's all you're getting in your code. You'll need to append each letter you get in the loop to a String variable and use that in the setText if you're trying to display all 50

Comment: You wanted to print out a random 50-character alphanumeric string? Just declare a string and concatenate to it in your for loop. I'll edit...